# Is there a conditional factor to check for filenames with letters only then execute the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code that will do the following:
1. Create folder based on the filename of the excel file in the same root folder
2. Move the excel file to the newly created folder with the same name

I'm having a problem in setting up the code that will check the excel files in the folder as it contains other excel files that I want to skip. The difference between the filenames is that the one I want to exclude are the filenames with a date at the start of the file name.

Here's what I have so far

```
Sub Create_Folder()

Dim ParentFolder As String

ParentFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path

myFile = Dir(ParentFolder)

Do While myFile <> "Australia Formatting" 'Or "20*"
    Debug.Print myFile
    Debug.Print Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, "_") - 1)
    MkDir (ParentFolder & Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, "_") - 1))
    Name ParentFolder & myFile As ParentFolder & Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, "_") - 1) & "\" & myFile
    myFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Create_Folder()

Dim ParentFolder As String
dim s as string

ParentFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

myFile = Dir(ParentFolder & "*.xl??") 'only want to look at excel files

Do While myFile <> "" 'keep looking until all files have been checked
    if myfile ="Australia Formatting" Or isdate(left(myfile,8)) then
          'skip
    else
       s=Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, "_") - 1)
       MkDir (ParentFolder & s)
       Name ParentFolder & myFile As ParentFolder & s & "\" & myFile
   end if
    myFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

'done on my phone so i can't test this - may be typos

Comment: I can't seem to make this work as it is still getting the files with dates in their filenames.

Comment: How does the date appear at the start of the filename? I assumed dd-mm-yy (or mm-dd-yy)